# Multivariable unconstrained optimization

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, optimization

I was just wondering how to answer this kind of question:

[image]

How do I answer this question using concepts such as stationary point, directional derivative, and linear independence?

Answer (score 0):

Brief outline: The vectors (1, 1) and (1, -1) are linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then the gradient of $f$ at $x^*$ is equal to $0$, and hence $x^*$ is a stationary point of $f$.  Try and fill in the details yourself!

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much. How do you know that the derivative of f at x* is equal to 0 though? At what point is it equal to 0? Also, when you say derivative, you mean gradient or directional derivative?

Comment: I meant gradient, I'll amend that to clarify.

Comment: The gradient of $f$ at $x^*$ is zero, which you should be able to prove using ideas from multivariable calculus

Comment: i was wondering if you could show how the fact that 'v1, v2,.... vn are linearly independent vectors' implies that the gradient of f at x* is equal to 0.